# What can I do to troubleshoot sync errors in Tidalis?

Tags: networking, tidalis

Any time we try to do a custom map on Tidalis, we get out of sync errors after a short time. Are there settings we can set, or something else we can do, to alleviate this? I'd really like to play some custom maps. Perhaps networking settings? We're both on Windows 7 64-bit and adventure mode seems to work fine.

The game is

http://store.steampowered.com/app/40420/

and

http://www.arcengames.com/tidalis_features.php

Comment: Sounds like poor programming - probably not a whole lot you can do other than play on a LAN not hooked up to internet and hope no packets get dropped anyways.  Also, email the creators and complain :)

Comment: well with starcraft and C&C generals I believe there were special settings you could make to your network or network adapter temporarily to help the issue not happen as often, that's what I was looking for.